# Creating a trigger that manipultes a field in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Guys, I have a table called tblNames and one of my fields in this table is called 'UpFileName'. Is it possible to create an insert trigger that would automatically replace all '%20' in the UpFileName field to underscores '_'?

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Why not just use `REPLACE(your_string, '%20', '_')` when you insert/update data into the table? REPLACE: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: @OMG Ponies , better yet a check constraint that fails if CHARINDEX finds any '%20' in the column! make the application write correct data!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it is like this, replace ID with the PK of your table

```
CREATE TRIGGER  trTriggerName  ON  tblNames   
 AFTER INSERT  AS  
UPDATE tblNames 
   SET UpFileName = replace(UpFileName,'%20','_') 
FROM tblNames t
JOIN INSERTED i ON t.ID = i.ID
```

However if you don't want people to insert certain types of data then use check constraints. Right now you are doing extra work for every inserts because this trigger fires